# Inquiry about how to center in parts except tag in IEEEeqnarray environment

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

I am writing a paper in the form of a two-column IEEE standard journal.
When I use the IEEEeqnarray environment, the equations are aligned based on the full width of the column.
However, in other environments (e.g., equation, align, etc.), the equations are aligned based on the width of the column except the tag parts.
Is there an option or a way in the IEEEeqnarray environment to align the equations based on the width of the column except the tag parts?

---

Example case is as follows:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{l'l'l}
    \IEEEyesnumber\IEEEyessubnumber*
    \pP & \maximize_{\bx} & f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

The result is as follows (I added "aaaaa ..." to explicitly show the width of the column):

[image: ddd]

Comment: Can you not use `IEEEeqnarray`. Not joking, but amsmath has the full toolbox. So why bother?

Comment: @Symbol1 I want to make a formula with 3 columns, with displaystyle format, and with tags for each row such as (6a), (6b), ....Can you recommend an environment that fits in my case?

Comment: I am pretty sure `align` allows more than 2 columns. BTW, amsmath environments align things w.r.t. the full column if the content is not too long. You need to do some tests to know the exact behavior. I can't say anything for sure.

Comment: Please, provide MWE! All displayed equation are equal centered in columns, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Zarko I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consult [Stefan Moser's tutorial](https://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf) for details about `IEEEeqnarray`. Section 5.1 has the solution.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\pP}{(\mathrm{P})}
\newcommand{\bx}{\mathbf{x}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maximize}{maximize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{l'l'l}
\IEEEyesnumber\IEEEyessubnumber*
\pP & \maximize_{\bx} & f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7, x_8, x_9)
\IEEEeqnarraynumspace
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added `newtx` because my eyes bleed when seeing text in Times and math in Computer Modern.

Comment: This is exactly what I want.